# include_once causing a 505 on php script

Tags: php

I have a form that will send data to the following PHP script. but it will then redirect to a 505 page. when I remove the include_once line, it will pass.

```
<?php
    include_once('db.php');
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo 'hello';
    } else {
        //if submit button is not clicked
        header('Location:register.html');   
    }
?>
```

[image]

This is the directory structure,
1 - form
2 - php script
3 - db script used in include_once

Following are the PHP version info

```
Apache/2.4.47 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1k PHP/7.3.28 Server at localhost Port 80
```

Comment: The file db.php and the file with the form are in separate folder but you call it with relative path and for this the load fails. From the IMG it's not clear dB.php folder's name. If it is "PHP" you have to change your include statement with include_once('php/db.php');

Comment: nope this is not related to the path, if the path is wrong I'm getting a separate error on the PHP script it self without any redirects @Stefino76

Answer (score 0, accepted):

worked on the following versions,
PHPmyadmin : Version information: 4.7.9
PHP version: 5.6.34